# Why 0 ** 0 equals 1 in python

Tags: python, math

Why does `0 ** 0` equal `1` in Python? Shouldn't it throw an exception, like `0 / 0` does?

Comment: Since x^0 = 1...

Comment: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node14.html

Comment: Because it *should* equal 1?

Comment: @AndersLindahl: Calculus teaches us that 0^0 is an indeterminate form. Hence why the OP is asking.

Comment: Related: [Zero to Zero power](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/11155/21440).

Comment: see this as well : http://goo.gl/Ewhjf

Comment: +1: For enlightening me.

Comment: @AndersLindahl, oh please, I could say that 0^x = 0...

Comment: Also, I've never seen a question with such controversial votes on both the question itself _and_ the answers.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Wikipedia has interesting coverage of the [history and the differing points of view on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) the value of `0 ** 0`:

> The debate has been going on at least since the early 19th century. At that time, most mathematicians agreed that `0 ** 0 = 1`, until in 1821 Cauchy listed `0 ** 0` along with expressions like `0⁄0` in a table of undefined forms. In the 1830s Libri published an unconvincing argument for `0 ** 0 = 1`, and Möbius sided with him...

As applied to computers, [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) recommends several functions for computing a power. It defines `pow(0, 0)` and `pown(0, 0)` as returning `1`, and `powr(0, 0)` as returning `NaN`.

Most programming languages follow the convention that `0 ** 0 == 1`. Python is no exception, both for integer and floating-point arguments.

Comment: I always thought that 0 ^ 0 is undefined, just like division by 0, but  never thought it could be so tricky. I think the explanation on wikipedia is very good, also explaining why other people think it should be 1, and it also covers the answer to my question, related to Python.

Answer (score 9):

consider `x^x`:

Using limits we can easily get to our solution and rearranging `x^x` we get :

```
x^x= exp(log(x^x))
```

Now , we have from:

```
lim x->0 exp(log(x^x))= exp(lim x->0 xlog(x)) = exp(lim x->0 log(x)/(x^-1))
```

Applying `L'Hôpital` rule , we get :

```
exp(lim x^-1/(-x^-2)) = exp(lim x->0 -x) = exp(0) = 1=x^x
```

But according to Wolfram Alpha `0**0` is indeterminate and following explanations were obtained by them :

> 0^0 itself is undefined. The lack of a well-defined meaning for this
>   quantity follows from the mutually contradictory facts that a^0 is
>   always 1, so 0^0 should equal 1, but 0^a is always 0 (for a>0), so 0^0
>   should equal 0. It could be argued that 0^0=1 is a natural definition
>   since lim_(n->0)n^n=lim_(n->0^+)n^n=lim_(n->0^-)n^n=1.
>   However, the limit does not exist for general complex values of n. Therefore, the choice of
>   definition for 0^0 is usually defined to be indeterminate."

Comment: You also could show that lim x->0 C/x = Inf (where C is some constant), but still, division by zero is undefined. So, C/x, when x->0 isn't the same as C/0. The same principle apply for x^x, you showed it is 1 when x->0, but that doesn't tell anything about the actual 0^0.

Answer (score -5):

2^2 = (1+1)*(1+1) = 4 (two objects occured two times)

2^1 = (1+1)*1     = 2 (two objects occured one time)

2^0 = (1+1)*0     = 0 (two objects did not occur)

1^2 = 1    *(1+1) = 2 (one object occured two times)

1^1 = 1    *1     = 1 (one object occured one time)

1^0 = 1    *0     = 0 (one object did not occur)

0^2 = 0    *(1+1) = 0 (zero objects occured twice)

0^1 = 0    *1     = 0 (zero objects occured once)

0^0 = 0    *0     = 0 (zero objects did not occur)

Therefore you cannot make something from nothing!