# A surprise with 1**math.nan and 0j**math.nan

Tags: python, floating-point, nan, ieee-754

I'm surprised that

```
>>> import math
>>> 1**math.nan
1.0
```

And while we are at it, also that

```
>>> 0j**math.nan
0j
```

I didn't find any other examples. Is there a reason or some logic I've missed that makes this the right choice? Or is this a slip?

I was expecting `nan`. As for every other number except `1` or `0j`.

**Edit 1:** Thanks to jedwards's comment below I have a reference. But I still don't understand why. Why was this decided as the standard? Also, couldn't find reference to `0j**mat.nan`...

**Edit 2:** So following the answers below and some other stuff, the logic may be this one: Any calculation involving `nan` should return `nan` unless the calculation is always returning the same answer regardless of arguments. In such cases, the fact that we have `nan` as an argument should not affect the result and we should still get the fixed answer.

This certainly explains `1**math.nan` and `math.nan**0`. This also explains why `0**math.nan` gives `nan` and not `0` (since `0**n` is `0` for all but when `n=0` where it results with `1`), and might be stretched to cover why `math.nan*0` is `nan` if we agree that the argument need not be finite.

But if this is the logic behind the scene, then `0j**math.nan` should have been `nan`, since `0j**n` is `0` for all `n`'s except `n=0` where `0j**0` is `1`. So... does `0j**math.nan` have different reasoning? or is it a problem in implementation?

Comment: There is definitely logic behind it -- an IEEE standard if I'm not mistaken.  Let me try to find the relevant docs.

Comment: Where does your surprise come from? What did you expect these expressions would evaluate to instead?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414430/why-0-0-equals-1-in-python

Comment: nan**0 == 1 another surprise for your list

Comment: I was wrong about it being IEEE-754, it looks like it's the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), Annex F (`1**NaN` is specified in F.9.44, for example)

Comment: 522 pages of light bedtime reading

Comment: One great thing of SO is that there is always one guy who actually RTFM.

Comment: @jedwards, thanks. But I still don't understand "why?". Also couldn't find a reference to `0j`.

Comment: Regarding the Python 3.x tags, this can be reproduced in Python 2.x using `1**float('nan')` and `0j**float('nan')` with the same behavior.

Comment: @rp.beltran - Added python-2 tag.

Comment: Related: https://bugs.python.org/issue15996 - `0j**math.nan` => `pow(0j, complex(float('nan')))`

Comment: Simple answer: the Python devs have spent time getting the corner cases right for `**` on floats, but no-one has looked at the complex `pow` corner cases in detail. On a system with IEEE 754 doubles, plain old `**` for floats follows the various standards out there (IEEE 754-2008, C99 Annex F, etc.). `**` for complex has never been fixed up properly for special values and corner cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863619/why-does-nan0-1) which in turns quotes IEEE 754 (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Function_definition)),

> The 2008 version of the IEEE 754 standard says that pow(1,qNaN) and pow(qNaN,0) should both return 1 since they return 1 whatever else is used instead of quiet NaN.

For details see page 56 of [IEEE 754 2008](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/%7Etsimo1/CMSC455/IEEE-754-2008.pdf):

> pow(x, ±0) is 1 for any x (even a zero, quiet NaN, or infinity)
>
> pow(±0, y) is ±∞ and signals the divideByZero exception for y an odd

Thus, the reasoning seems to be that no matter what number k is in the exponent, `1^k = 1`, `1^Nan` should also be 1. Why that reasoning is reasonable (I'm sure it is) I'll need to dig further.

Personally, I think this makes sense - `Nan` doesn't really exist in math, it's just that our floating point representation can't handle it (or, Nan is "the computation is too much, this is some number but not sure which"). Thus, `1^Nan` could be 1 to an arbitrary power (not 1 to something that is not a number), but since the answer will always be 1, it can only help if we define `1^Nan` to be 1.

Comment: Indeed I can see why this makes sense. But what about `0j**math.nan`?

Comment: @Aguy: I think that is a bug since 0 ** float('nan') = nan.

Comment: That looks like an illegally distributed PDF of IEEE 754. :-(

Comment: @MarkDickinson: It looks like class material thus I thought it could be legit - feel free to edit it out if you are sure it is illegal, though. It's always just a Google away anyway.